# $f(x)~dx = P[x < X \le x + dx]$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Given a continuous r.v. X with pmf $f_X(x)$.

$f(x_1)~dx = P[x_1 < X \le x_1 + dx]$

however, why doesn't:

$f_X(x_1) = P[X=x_1]$

If that's the case,  how would you find the value of $f_X(x_1)$ in order to plot this point on the curve of $f_X(x)$?

Comment: If $X$ is a continuous random variable, then $p(X = x_1) = 0$. For example, suppose you pick a real number between $0$ and $1$ at random and the result is $X$. What's the probability that $X$ is equal to $1/3$? It would be an unthinkable coincidence if, out of all the numbers in this interval, the one we selected just happened to be exactly equal to $1/3$.

Comment: the assumption for continuous r.v.'s is that between any two points is an infinite space of subdivided points... (like zeno's paradox)  ...  the probably of selecting one point out of an infinite number of points is zero...  if between any two points there were finite number of points, then this would be a discrete r.v. and the probability of selecting a single point out of a finite set would be a finite number.

Comment: @pico What you are saying is not true. The image of a Poisson distributed random variable is infinite but each point in the image is taken with probability $>0$.

Comment: Poisson is a discrete r.v. with a PMF instead of a PDF, if X is a poison r.v. then it can only take on integral values... for instance,  is there such a thing as $p_X(\pi)$? Consider posion pmf: $p_X(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{\lambda^x~ e^{-\lambda}}{x!} & x=0,1,2, \cdots \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Comment: @pico I think I misinterpreted your statement „ the probably of selecting one point out of an infinite number of points is zero“ which is not correct. Still, you should realise that there are also random variables which are neither continuous nor discrete